# Spring cloud config server sends spring security login form instead of logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring cloud config server to store `logback.xml` configuration.
Here's my consuming microservice (the one which is spring cloud config client) `bootstrap.properties` file:

```
server.port=5555
spring.application.name=test-ms
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.username=root
spring.cloud.config.password=123123
logging.config=http://localhost:8888/test-ms/development/master/logback.xml
```

This worked fine until I turned on spring security on my spring cloud config server. After that it sends
spring security login form instead of `logback.xml` so I'm getting an exception:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'http://localhost:8888/test-ms/development/master/logback.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from http://localhost:8888/test-ms/development/master/logback.xml
```

...

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://localhost:8888/test-ms/development/master/logback.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 5; The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
```

because as I said it is getting spring security login page instead of `logback.xml`.
But I need to have authentication on my spring cloud config server. 
I tries to put user and password into url: `logging.config=http://user:passwordlocalhost:8888/test-ms/development/master/logback.xml` but it didn't help.
How can I point my spring cloud config client to xml on spring cloud config server?

Comment: The problem is not related with the config server, it is sending you to the "login" page because logback is not able to download the configuration (because is protected). I dont know if it is possible to tell logback how to download a protected resouce, I think that the best way to solve this problem is a .properties file: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Comment: @RaulCabreraA. Unfortunately there's no way to configure rolling policy through properties AFAIK. Maybe I'm mistaken?